# Showing a zero in front of a number in Excel

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel

How do you get a zero to show up in front of a number if the numbers in the column are all different sizes, such as bank account numbers?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a format string, such as "000 0000 0000" to force a number like 2031234567 to be shown as "020 3123 4567" - the "`0`" placeholder will force the zero to show, even if it is mathematically insignificant, such as in a bank account number, or phone number, etc.

Answer (score 2):

### Adding apostrophe (`'`)

You can simply put an apostrophe (`'`) in front of the number, it will be formatted as text.

For example, input `'0012345` will display `0012345`.

### Format at text

You can also format the cells as text, so that all leading zeros can be displayed without needing to add apostrophe (`'`) every time.

---

### Sidenote

It is recommended to format bank account number as text instead of number. Because Excel **stores only 15 significant digits in a number**. The 16th digit will be lost for credit card number or if the bank account number is too long.

Reference: [I can't write credit card number when I write the last number becomes 0](https://superuser.com/questions/486280/i-cant-write-credit-card-number-when-i-write-the-last-number-becomes-0/486725#486725)